# How to name columns in Looker based on the current month?

Tags: looker

How to name columns in Looker based on the current month?

I have a dashboard which shows sales for the current month and past two months. I want these columns to be dynamically named for eg Sales_Sept, Sales_Aug and Sales_July. Depending on the month we are looking at the names should appear accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot by the month name column for dynamically named columns.

```
view: table_1 {
  derived_table: {
    sql: SELECT *
         FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<DATE DATE, A FLOAT64>>[
         ('2020-12-01', 10),
         ('2020-12-15', 30),
         ('2021-01-01', 30),
         ('2021-01-15', 60)])
       ;;
  }
  dimension_group: row {
    type: time
    datatype: date
    sql: ${TABLE}.date ;;
  }
  dimension: a {
    type: number
  }
  measure: total_a {
    type: sum
    sql: ${a} ;;
  }
}

explore: table_1 {}
```

Aggregate to month name:

[image: Row totals for the last two months]

Pivot by month name:

[image: Row totals as named columns by month]